# How to make a timer that redo the event programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

So I want to perform some button clicks say every in 10 second, and here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Main : Form {
    public Main() {        
        InitializeComponent();

        // add timer to do button clicking every 10 seconds
        double elapse = 10000;
        System.Timers.Timer timer2 = new Time(elapse);
        timer2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ResetEvent);
        timer2.AutoReset = true;
        timer2.Start();
    }

    private void ResetEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            Refresh_Button.PerformClick();
            Process_Button.PerformClick();
        } catch { }
    }

    private void Refresh_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // some code
    }  

    private void Process_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with the code? How can I make it works?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Have you put a breakpoint in to see if your handler is called?  Your empty `catch` might be eating an exception and allowing things to happily progress.

Comment: what happens when you step through the code ? at sometime one would expect you to stop the timer and to restart the timer , [How to Call a button 's Click Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkkb40tf(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: look at this code here and you will see where you went wrong http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is accessing UI thread illegally in [`Elapsed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) event of [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

You are calling `Refresh_Button.PerformClick();` in `Elapsed` event of timer that cause an cross thread exception that you are hiding it.

To access UI thtread and call `PerformClick()` method of `Refresh_Button`:

```
Refresh_Button.Invoke(new Action(() => { Refresh_Button.PerformClick(); }));
```

Also you can use [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and handle [`Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event and call `Refresh_Button.PerformClick();` manually.

**Note:**

- Don't hide exceptions. If you hide exceptions, such problems will hide and finding them will be really hard.
- It's better to put the logic a method and instead of calling `PerformClick`, call that method.
- If you don't need a different thread, [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) whould be enough.